# why are assigning functions to identifiers necessary while invoking them?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'd like to take an example code for this:

```
def coun(n):
    count = 0
    def counter():
        nonlocal count
        if count < n:
            count += 1
        return count
    return counter

cntrl = coun(4)
print(cntrl())
```

why must we assign the function to an identifier, further more in the print statement, the cntrl is invoked using parenthesis, and in the return statement of the function coun the counter is not returned using parenthesis. What is this?(I'm just a novice at python)

Comment: you call a function by adding `()` after it, if you don't want to call the function (or any other thing) you don't add parenthesis, in this case you are returning the function itself back, not it's return value where as `cntrl = coun(4)` you are calling `coun` and getting it's return value.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `return counter()` to call the function immediately completely defeating the purpose of defining it within another function, or you could do `print(cntrl)` to see the representation of the function itself without actually invoking it... but I think the standard here is "you call something when you want to call it" and not anywhere else.

Comment: That's really a wrapper function you've got there. You're invoking the outer function by assigning it to an identifier, and then by calling the inner one, you should call identifier. Another method is to do `@count` above another function to wrap it. Find out more about wrappers / decorators from [here](http://hangar.runway7.net/python/decorators-and-wrappers).

Comment: Names are definitely not necessary. `(lambda x: x+1)(2)` -> `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's not**

Because you are doing `return counter` rather than `return counter()` you are returning a function rather than the result of that function, in order to get the result you need to call this function. You can do this, as you have done, by assigning it to a variable or you can call it immediately with the usual function call convention:

```
print(coun(4)())
```

Comment: The typo would make sense as a comment, I'm not sure it really belongs in your answer.

Comment: @Jack Aidley , your answer exactly hits the head of my question, but why is the parenthesis required after coun(4) as: print(coun(4)()) and not as: print(coun(4))  ?

Comment: Because `coun` _returns_ a function `coun(4)` _is_ a function, and you need to call a function to get its result. The way you call a function is with parenthesis after the function. This is exactly the same as you need to put `(4)` after `coun`.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning functions to identifiers isn't neccesary to invoke them.

Consider simple example:

```
def function_factory():
    def f(x):
        return x
    return f
```

You may assign function returned from factory to identifier and use it as any other named function:

```
my_f = function_factory()
assert my_f(1) == 1
```

Or you can drop intermediate assignment and do it in one line:

```
assert function_factory()(1) == 1
```

Comment: wow thanks! Though could you explain why the assert statement is used and why is it necessary(if not in this particular code in some programs.)

Comment: [Python docs: Assert statements are a convenient way to insert debugging assertions into a program](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement)